# Pointers to char - Increment operator

Tags: c, pointers, operators

I am afraid I did not get correctly the precedence between operators. The following program works differently than expected:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[] = "abc";
    char *p;
    int i;

    p = a;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)          /* First case */
        printf("%c\n", *p++);

    printf("a = %s\n", a);

    p = a;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)        /* Second case */
        printf("%c\n", (*p)++);
    printf("a = %s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

First case: according to this [table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), `*p++` is `*(p++)`. I increment the address pointed by `p`, *then* I dereference it. Why it returns `abc`, then, and not `bc + "value beyond string"`?

I encounter a similar problem with the second case, with the expression `(*p)++`. In this case, the parentheses make me increase the *dereferentiated* value of p. Hence, I expect the expression to return `bcd` rather than `dbc`.

Comment: Because `p++` is **post**-increment.

Comment: I am ok with the first case, then. In any case, the address pointed by `p` is incremented after being dereferentiated.  But what happens in the second case?  It 's like the string is "circularly moved forward", if I am able to express myself.

Comment: `*p++` dereferences the pointer to read what it points to and then increments the pointer. `(*p)++` increments what it points to.

Comment: In the second case, you're updating the value `p` *points to*, not the value of `p` itself, so you're not iterating through the string - you're just setting the first element of `a` to `'b'`, then `'c'`, then `'d'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case it is performing the pointer increment *after* it's value is returned, because the operation is a *post*-increment.

In the second case you are incrementing `*p`, 3 times in the loop without changing the value of `p` itself. So the first element of `a` (which `p` is pointing to) is incremented 3 times resulting in `'a'+3='d'`. The rest of the elements remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

FIRST CASE:

Iteration 1: i=0, *p = a, a point to 'abc'.
now after this statement p will point to 'b' and i =1

Iteration 2: i=1, *p = b, a point to 'abc'.
now after this statement p will point to 'c' and i =2

Iteration 3: I=2, *p = c, a point to 'abc'.
now after this statement p will point to null termination char and i=3

Iteration 4: loop breaks, a still points to 'abc'

SECOND CASE:

Iteration 1: i=0, *p = 'a', a points to 'abc'.
After this statement the value at which p points increases thus a points to 'bbc' and i=1

Iteration 2: i=1, *p ='b', a point to 'bbc'.
After this statement the value at which p points increases thus a points to 'cbc' and i=2

Iteration 3: i=2, *p ='c', a points to 'cbc'.
After this statement the value at which p points increases thus a points to 'dbc' and i= 3

Iteration 4: loop breaks and a points to 'dbc'
And p points to 'd'